# hide a view field content for anonymous only?

Tags: views

How can I hide a field for the anonymous user in a view?

Logged in users should still be able to see the field.

(Drupal 8.3.0)

Comment: Take a look at the field permissions module. It has an 8.x release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in Views like you say, you can simply add an access restriction by role. Set it to 'authenticated' - the view display will only show for authenticated roles.

Outside of Views displays, you will need another mechanism like [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to control visibility.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill for just one field, but you could take a look at the Field Permissions module: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions. This module allows you to set permissions on a per-field basis, so you can just remove all permissions for anonymous users for this field.

Comment: Thanks, I want to try it. Is there a another way to do it directly in views?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is not the cleanest solution, but it's simple.

Place the following code in your module's *.module file. So, if you're module is called **module_name**, place it in **module_name.module** file. And the function name should begin with **module_name** as written below:

```
function module_name_views_pre_build(ViewExecutable $view) {
    if ($view->id() == 'view_name') {
        if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
            unset($view->field['field_first_name']);
        }
    }

}
```

For more information check [hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/hooks/8.2.x).

Comment: Is that a function for a module or for a theme?

Comment: @FrankGiesecke This function is for a module, yes. I looked a lot and unfortunately, I was unable to find a clean method to do the same in a theme. If you really need to do in a theme, you can  override one of view templates (e.g. **views-view-fields--VIEW-NAME.html.twig**) and render that particular field only if user is authenticated using **logged_in** twig function. But this is really not the best way to go. Better do that in a custom module or use **field_permissions** contrib module as others pointed out.

Comment: where has this code to be placed? in the *.module file?

Comment: Yes, in a *.module file. I should have been more specific in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. -> unexpected error, also with the empty function:
function mymodule_views_pre_build(ViewExecutable $view) {}

Comment: update: runs with: mymodule_views_pre_prebuild(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view), but no change to the view after log out

Comment: @FrankGiesecke There might be a couple of things at fault: 1) Make sure "mymodule" is the same as the machine name of your custom module; 2) After you add that (hook) function, you must clear the cache at **/config/development/performance** and click **Clear all cache**. Otherwise, I'd have to know a bit more details. Please let me know if you find the reason!

Comment: @FrankGiesecke If you have more questions, please "move this discussion to a chat" as it suggests, so that we look at it at lengths. I don't have high enough reputation to do it.